# How to execute a private transaction in quorum

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum

I am currently learning quorum. I was able to build two node environment by referring to "Creating a network from scratch" in the following quorum official link, and successed to attach node1 using geth.ipc.

[quorum](https://docs.goquorum.com/en/latest/Getting%20Started/Creating-A-Network-From-Scratch/)

But I don't know how to create private-transactions between two nodes as a flow after this.
Does it have any other setting files and script files its need?

static-nodes.json file is below.

```js
[
    "enode://cbe04627713bfdc6f416a8ed97fc12f602ff85c4f775412100cf69e77bf1de20b54b84c6e799e05ea0e921ad84a8b3d0dfc80ad8b868af29a89b2f0613d3cb15@127.0.0.1:21001?discport=0&raftport=50001",
    "enode://f1956696a0dbdfc90befcc1030be83cdb5926e2f5193c6c2e069dd9ba42b9fd5f0d81cfa27cb26b01c959bcd4130bedb182bf9dc3e771b8385e94fab07738b33@127.0.0.1:21002?discport=0&raftport=50002"
]
```

genesis.json file is below.

```js
{
    "alloc": {
      "0x4045b87bfb1fb46177b09284d0d9845d29e82bb5":{
        "balance": "1000000000000000000000000000"
      },
      "0x48c0b6c52ca9cd1f2380213e82ddeb4c5a7de0d3":{
        "balance": "2000000000000000000000000000"
      }
    },
   "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
   "config": {
     "homesteadBlock": 0,
     "byzantiumBlock": 0,
     "chainId": 10,
     "eip150Block": 0,
     "eip155Block": 0,
     "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
     "eip158Block": 0,
     "isQuorum": true
    },
   "difficulty": "0x0",
   "extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
   "gasLimit": "0xE0000000",
   "mixhash": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000647572616c65787365646c6578",
   "nonce": "0x0",
   "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
   "timestamp": "0x00"
  }
```

Comment: https://docs.goquorum.com/en/latest/Getting%20Started/running/#creating-private-transactionscontracts ?

Answer (score 2):

As per the response from Florian - follow the instructions in the docs for [Creating Private Transactions/Contracts](https://docs.goquorum.com/en/latest/Getting%20Started/running/#creating-private-transactionscontracts).

Make sure you have a transaction manager running for each node (e.g. Tessera).

Essentially you just need to add a 'privateFor' field to the transaction; this must contain the public key of the private transaction participant (i.e. the public key for the transaction manager on the other node).

BTW Assuming you're using a recent version of Quorum, I'd suggest also adding the following to your genesis:

`"constantinopleBlock": 0,`